# What is the opposite exercise of push ups?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, strength-training, bodyweight-exercises, push-ups

I've been doing push ups on a daily basis, and I feel like I need to also train the opposite muscles, to make sure I'm training evenly. What would be a good counter-exercise for push ups?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BBBentOverRow.html) is the exercise that best antagonizes the push-up.

It's an easy conclusion to make just by considering the force vector of the push-up.  The direction of force is outward and perpendicular to the body.  If you reverse that vector, you have a row.

To clarify further, imagine only the upper arm and the chest when doing a push-up (imagine you just have stub arms).  What's happening is that your [stub] arms are adducting -- they're coming together.  The pectorals are driving this movement.  To be scientific, the primary movers in this adduction are:

- [Pectoralis Major](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/PectoralisSternal.html) (and [clavicular head](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/PectoralisClavicular.html), [minor](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/PectoralisMinor.html))
- [Anterior Deltoid](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/DeltoidAnterior.html)
- [Triceps](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/TricepsBrachii.html)

Again to use the stub arm image, think of the same thing when doing a row.  The stub arms are *abducting* -- they're moving apart.  Your back is also retracting to pull the weight back even further, and providing [isometric contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_exercise) so your arms don't get ripped out of their sockets.  Now think about all the muscles that need to be involved for this to happen:

- [Rhomboids](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/Rhomboids.html)
- [Traps](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/TrapeziusMiddle.html) (and [lower](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/TrapeziusLower.html))
- [Lats](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/LatissimusDorsi.html)
- [Posterior Deltoid](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/DeltoidPosterior.html)
- [Biceps](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/BicepsBrachii.html)
- (There are quite a few others)

The reason we can't consider the [pull-up](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/BWPullup.html) a very *complete* antagonist exercise to the push-up is that it predominantly targets the lats.  It's missing a couple of key components:

- Core involvement (both the row and the push-up require significant core involvement to execute)
- Scapular retraction (though some adduction occurs, it is less pronounced than the row).

We could consider the pull-up to be a downward *rotation* rather than abduction.  The pull-up could be considered the antagonist exercise to the overhead [press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BBMilitaryPress.html) (*upward* rotation). Read more about scapular and clavicular articulations [here](http://www.exrx.net/Articulations/Scapula.html).

Answer (score 7):

[Pull ups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/BWPullup.html) (or chin ups), if you have a pull up bar available – or something else where you can do pull ups. They not just train the shoulders and the upper back but a lot of other muscles, too.
If you don't have any special equipment or can't do pull ups yet, go with [inverted rows](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BWSupineRow.html), you can do them lying under a table.

You should try to counter every push movement – one where you exert force away from your body – with a pull movement that works in the opposite way.

Answer (score 6):

The most true "opposite" exercise to the push-up is the [let me up](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/11/06/inverted-row-are-you-missing-out-on-this-great-exercise/), or inverted row. These preserve the posture, bodyweight aspect, and arm positioning of push-ups for a true mirror-image exercise. The barbell row's different form (arched back, pulling toward lower ribs) works muscles farther down the back that are silent in push-ups.

Answer (score 1):

For any antagonist exercise, reverse the primary exercise, and keep the same angles and range of motion.  For the pushup, that would be an inverted row with your hands on a fixed bar, with your feet elevated on a box such that your body is horizontal at the top of the row.
A ring row (with hands on rings or a suspension trainer) would similarly reverse a ring or suspension-trainer pushup.
You can do that with many upper body exercises (overhead presses/pullups, flyes/reverse flyes, incline presses/pulldowns, etc.).

Comment: Antagonist exercise?

Comment: :) I'm sure they mean "antagonist muscle exercise".